# Fancybox 2.1... scrolls page to top when opening

Tags: scroll, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm having an issue with Fancybox scrolling the underlying page to it's top as soon as the modal window opens.  When it closes it doesn't return to where the user was either.  It forces the user to have to scroll back down the page to the point they left off.

Any insights?

Comment: check if this helps https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/630

Comment: Thanks but that seems to be for an older version of Fancybox and/or I don't want to use the min-height: 100% for the same reason the person past the jump didn't want to.

Comment: If you are using fancybox v2.1.5 it seems that the issue has been fixed in the latest master that you can download form here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip so no more hacks to either the js or css files.

Answer (score 4):

In **jquery.fancybox.css** > **fancybox-lock**...

**Change...**

```
overflow: hidden !important;
```

**to...**

```
overflow: visible !important;
```

Answer (score 4):

To fix it here I used a built in helper function, this is how I set it up now:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    locked: false
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when opened fancybox content was iframe. I found out that there was some JS (in my page, loaded into iframe) containing .focus() directive. Removing this, bug was fixed...